# Laravel project hosting: file uploads and images directory

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, hosting

I am done with a Laravel project and I plan to host it on AWS EC2. I am still learning how that works.
My project includes file uploading. I upload my files in Laravel's public folder.
Similarly, I store some images in the public folder and use laravel's asset function in the img tag to retrieve it.
I am worried nonetheless that these paths would not be recognized when I host my application.
Am I using the correct directory to store my images and uploaded files?

If not which local directory should the images and files be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public folder is correct and it will automatically access in images just in case if your images not accessible then you need to run a command `php artisan storage:link` it will link your folder as storage and then you need to make storage folder permission to 777 then it will work.